# Localizar un elemento con selenium en python sin hacerlo por Id?

Tags: python-3.x

¿Hay alguna forma de localizar un elemento html con selenium sin hacerlo por el id?

Necesito localizar un elemento input con selenium pero no me sirve hacerlo por id ya que este cambia continuamente en la web que uso. Tampoco puedo hacerlo por 'name', ni por 'class' ya que el elemento no tiene esas propiedades, asi que solo puedo hacerlo por TagName o por value.

He intentado hacerlo con `driver.find_element_by_tag_name('input')` pero el problema es que esta funcion retorna un objeto que no tiene indices ni puede ser iterado para encontrar el input especifico que necesito..

¿Que funcion de selenium se usaria para este caso?

Comment: `find_elements_by_tag_name()`(plural), Otra idea,  quizás identificar si su padre o un ancestro es un elemento con un atributo específico más fácil de localizar, y usar ese elemento para luego refinar la búsqueda del input dentro de el.

Comment: Sí el elemento no cambia su posición en la página podrías usar  `find_elements_by_xpath()`.  Si ambas opciones no te funcionaron, podrías agregar a la publicación la url de la página e indicar ducho elemento

Comment: soy principiante en la programacion, has probado con xpath?